# How to add id attribute to custom_logo in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In WordPress functions.php:

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-logo' );

function themename_custom_logo_setup() {
 $defaults = array(
 'height'      => 100,
 'width'       => 400,
 'flex-height' => true,
 'flex-width'  => true,
 'header-text' => array( 'site-title', 'site-description' ),
 );
 add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', $defaults );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'themename_custom_logo_setup' );
```

And in my header.php file I add this:

```
<div class="logo">
    <?php echo get_custom_logo(); ?>
</div>
```

I would like to add an id attribute to the resulting  tag.

So I want to get the next one:

```
<div class="logo">
    <img src="..." id="custom-logo" class="custom-logo" alt="...">
</div>
```

Comment: have you try : `$custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );` ?

Comment: Which part of the code where I should to enter this?

Comment: on page where custom logo is.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me :( .